# convergence of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence

> If $X_n\sim \text{Exp}(a_n)$, then
>   $$X_n\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{\longrightarrow}X\sim \text{Exp}(a)$$ as
>   $n\to\infty$ and $a_n\to a$, $n\geq$ 1.

I know that,

$\Pr(Y_n\geq a_n+\epsilon)=\Pr(X_i\geq a_n+\epsilon)^{n}=
\left(1-F_X(a_n+\epsilon)\right)^{n}$

$$F_n(x)=1-e^{-xa_n}\quad F_n(x)=1-(1-e^{a_n+\epsilon})^{n}.$$
Thus, this converge to $e^{a+\epsilon}$  right?

Comment: The power of $n$ in the second $F_n$ is incorrect. Recall that convergence in distribution is equivalent to convergence of the cdf at all continuity points of $F$.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  How did $x$ disappear from the right hand side in your second expression for $F_n(x)$?  Also a limit as $n \to \infty$ can't depend on $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the fact that $e^{-x a_n}$ is a *continuous function* of $a_n$.  This means we can "take the limit inside" like this:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x) &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1 - e^{-x a_n} \right ) \\
&= 1 - e^{- x \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n} \\
&= 1 - e^{- x a} .
\end{align}